# Convert string for XML (UTF-8)

Tags: php

I have a string such as `H&eacute;l&egrave;ne Lee, Christophe Farnarier (co) 2010 | The First Rasta | 86 min.` and I need to convert it so I can print it in a XML node. Which is currently giving me an error **XML Parsing Error: undefined entity** at the `&eacute;` part.

Is there a way to convert it to the #275; or what ever it is numerical entry? Or another way to do this? It is not just `&eacute;` there are several other special characters as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no built-in PHP function that able to convert **HTML entities** into numeric entities that acceptable by XML

search for `php numeric entities` lead to here : http://www.lazycat.org/php-convert-entities.html , the conversion mentioned in the article should have covered most of the **HTML entities**

Answer (score 0):

Use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) to decode the entities back into their original characters. There is no need to use entities here.

The third parameter specifies the encoding - it defaults to ISO-8859-1 before PHP 5.4, so be sure to specify UTF-8 explicitly.

Comment: I believe it defaults to iso-8850-1 (and to utf-8 in php 5.4)

Comment: Now I'm getting `unterminated entity reference Shout |`

Comment: @Steven needs more info. What does the decoded string look like?

Comment: You need to do htmlspecialchars after that. He's presumably got some & in there which need to stay encoded (or else look like unknown entities unterminated by a ; to the parser).